# merging linear lists - reconstruct railway network

Tags: algorithm, list, merge

I need to reconstruct the sequence of stations in a railway network from the sequences of single trips requested from a arbitrary station. There's no direction given in the data. But every request returns an terminal stop. The sequences of single trips can have gaps. 
The (end-) result is always a linear list - forking is not allowed.

For example:

Result trips from requested station "4" :

`4 - 3 - 2 - 1
 4 - 1
 4 - 5 - 6 
 4 - 8 - 9
 4 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9`

manually reordered:

`1 - 2 - 3 - 4
 1         - 4
           - 4 - 5 - 6
           - 4             - 8 - 9
           - 4     - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9`

After merging result should be:

`1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9`

start/stop: 1, 9

Is there an algorithm to calculate the resulting "rope of pearls" list? I tried to figure it out with perls graph-module, but no luck. My books on algorithms doesn't help either.

I think, there are pathologic cases, where multiple solutions are possible, depending on input data.

Maybe someone has an idea to solve it!

As you see in the answers, there is more than one solution. So here's a real-world dataset:

```
2204236 -> 2200007 -> 2200001
2204236 -> 2203095 -> 2203976 -> 2200225 -> 2200007 -> 2200001
2204236 -> 2204805 -> 2204813 -> 2204401 -> 2219633 -> 2204476 -> 2202024 -> 2202508 -> 2202110 -> 2202026
2204236 -> 2204813 -> 2204401 -> 2219633 -> 2202508 -> 2202110 -> 2202026 -> 3011047 -> 3011048 -> 3011049
2204236 -> 2204813 -> 2204401 -> 2219633 -> 2204476 -> 2202024 -> 2202508 -> 2202110 -> 2202352 -> 2202026
2204236 -> 2204813 -> 2204401 -> 2219633 -> 2204476 -> 2202024 -> 2202508 -> 2209637 -> 2202110
```

solution of the example data with perl:

```
use Graph::Directed;
use Graph::Traversal::DFS;

my $g = Graph::Directed->new;

$g->add_path(1,2,3,4);
$g->add_path(1,4);
$g->add_path(4,5,6);
$g->add_path(4,8,9);
$g->add_path(4,6,7,8,9);

print "The graph is $g\n";
my @topo = $g->toposort;
print "g toposorted = @topo\n";
```

Output

```
> The graph is 1-2,1-4,2-3,3-4,4-5,4-6,4-8,5-6,6-7,7-8,8-9
> g toposorted = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Using the other direction

```
$g->add_path(4,3,2,1);
$g->add_path(4,1);
$g->add_path(4,5,6);
$g->add_path(4,8,9);
$g->add_path(4,6,7,8,9);
```

reveals the second solution

```
The graph is 2-1,3-2,4-1,4-3,4-5,4-6,4-8,5-6,6-7,7-8,8-9
g toposorted = 4 3 2 1 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: `4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 3 - 2 - 1` is also a solution.

Comment: Why is this a solution? There is no connection between 9 and 3. 9 is connected only with 8.

Comment: My understanding of your problem is that you need to find such list of stations for which each of given lists would be a sublist. Both your and my solutions hold this property. Otherwise, I don't understand the term "connected".

Comment: Oh, OK now I have it. So in this example case there's no single solution.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the lists node links in a graph. `4-3-2-1` should mean 4 must come before 3, 3 before 2 and 2 before 1. So add arcs from 4 to 3, 3 to 2, 2 to 1.
Once you have all of those you run a topological sort(look it up on wikipedia) on the resulting graph. This will guarantee that the order you get will always respect the partial orderings you are given.

The only case when you are not going to find a solution is when the data is contradicting itself (if you have `4-3-2` and `4-2-3` there's no possible ordering).

You are right, there are multiple cases. Another good solution is `4-5-6-7-8-9-3-2-1`, for your example.

Comment: If I run an topological search on the complete graph, I get an error because of cycles in the graph.

Comment: @MPH Then there's no solution. Unless you have a mistake in the graph construction.

Comment: Ok, now it works! The graph has to be directed. Then there's no cycle in the graph and topological sort works.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal stop station is articulation node and it splits graph into multiple partitions: all nodes inside partition are reachable from one another, nodes in different partitions are reachable only via known terminal stop station. Number of partitions is 2 in your example, but may be much larger, e.g. consider star-like structure `1 - 2, 1 - 3, 1 - 4, 1 - 5`.

First of all you need to enumerate partitions. You treat your graph as undirected graph and run DFS from stop station in each of directions. At first run you discover partition #1, at second run partition #2 and so on.

Then you treat you graph as directed with stop station as root node for all partitions and run topological sorting (TS) for each of partitions.

Possible outcomes:

1. TS for one of partitions fails. This means there is no solution.
2. Number of partitions is one and TS for it succeeds. Solution is unique.
3. Number of partitions is more than one and TS succeeds for all of them. This means there are multiple solutions. To get any single valid result, you choose some partition and declare that it contains another terminal station. All other partitions are inserted into the first one in between arbitrary pair of nodes.